# Can you use Squiggly with a TLF text container or TextFlow?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, tlf

I'm creating my own TLF container as described in the TLF documentation but I want to use the Squiggly spell checker. I found a [tutorial](https://caleem.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/q-how-to-achieve-spell-check-in-flex-a-using-squiggly/) that describes how to use Squiggly but it does not show how to work with a TextFlow only TextArea. How do I use Squiggly with a TextFlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class called, "SpellUIForTLF" that supports TLF spell checking where you can pass in a reference to the TextFlow:

```
import com.adobe.linguistics.spelling.SpellUIForTLF;

SpellUIForTLF.enableSpelling(_textFlow, "en_US");
```